# Mapping 2d point to 3d coordinate

Tags: python, projection

I have two videos with a moving point in different views.

There have some markers in this two video. For example there have a five points objects in each videos but in different angle.

Is it possible for me to map the 2d point to 3d coordinate?

Comment: Please elaborate - the question is too vague. Do you know the coordinates of the two cameras with respect to each other? Do you have other markers in the video that you know the coordinates of relative to each other or to the cameras?

Comment: No, you may not know the coordinates of the two camera. But, there have some markers in this two video. For example there have a five points objects in each videos but in different angle.

Comment: You would need to estimate the camera parameters to get some mapping from 2D to 3D.  It'll be with respect to cameras though and you need to map that to whatever metric system from there.